# Backbone Views defined in Head not working unless using Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using the "[rails-backbone](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails#readme)" gem in my Rails 3.2 project. By this design my Backbone Views are loaded in the `<head>` tag. When using Routes everything works fine, but Views do not render if I try to use them directly without Routes. If I put the Views code in `<body>` everything works as expected.

Is there a way to make the Views work when defined in `<head>`?

Update:
in `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lv = new ListView();
</script>
```

in javascript file included in `<head>`:

```
window.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#node"), // This does not work
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
        this.el = $("#node"); // Works if I add this line
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
    }
});
```

As I understand it #node does not exist yet, which is why it is not bound to `el`. I don't quite understands when happens here: `var lv = new ListView()`, I thought I was creating an instance from a Class (I guess I'm getting a clone of an Object?). Is there another way of making the code work by modifying the code in `<body>` instead of the included javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by using a jQuery selector as the value for `el` in the view.

Read this:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! Especially this part: **THERE ARE NO CLASSES IN JAVASCRIPT**

Answer (score 0):

if you want something to work in the head, but after the DOM is ready, (And apparently since you're using jQuery)  just set up your views in the DOMReady event via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   ...
   //set up view here
   ...
 });
```

Comment: That, or better yet, don't call `render` in your initialize statement, and delay calling *that* until the DOM is ready.